# Is there a way to use Linux & Samba Server to mimic NTFS ACL's under a Windows Domain?

Tags: permissions, samba, active-directory, file-sharing, ntfs

Does anyone know of an up-to-date tutorial for this? I found this old doc from 2003: http://www.bluelightning.org/linux/samba_acl_howto/ . I've like to have a Linux server replace the Windows file servers for all the Windows workstations. However, NTFS ACL is important, as well as domain authentication. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes samba maps NTFS ACL's to posix ACL's - just make sure your disk is mounted with the ACL option

you need `map inherit acls = true` in the file share section of your samba config.

I highly recommend this book : http://au.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0782144284.html

Its kinda old now, but everything it says holds true.

Comment: Thanks. How are domain users and groups handled? Can the Linux box authenticate with the Windows DC's so that the users and groups are correct? What about files that have permissions for multiple specific users that may not be in a dedicated group, or multiple groups (but not a meta-group to contain them)?

Comment: You really should get the book i linked - it covers this very scenario ;-). Basically you need to use winbind on the Samba box to join it into the AD, and then it will see the users etc correctly. as for multiple acl's thats fine too.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I just wanted to make sure that was possible before I buy the book.